# How to disable video compressing when sharing

Tags: video, camera

When sharing video my windows phone automatically compress it. The video quality is much worse then original.

1. Does windows phone allows to turn off compressing video while sharing?
2. Can I force WP to share video only through WIFI connection?

Comment: Hi, I think item #2 is quite different and should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: Do you mean sharing by email or MMS? I can understand that here a large video file would be compressed. What is your objective? Would USB sync (via Zune or directly on a Windows Phone 8 device?) or uploading to SkyDrive work for you?

Comment: I just want to easily share videos with my family in good quality. I have unlimited Internet plan so I want o send videos in good quality. The best way for me is to share it by email so it is easy and fast. I don't want to go to home and get videos by zune and then share it.

Comment: I am interested in knowing the compression ratio. Does anyone know that ??

Comment: Are you on wp8?  If so you can use Bluetooth to share files easily.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to the "share..." menu for 3rd party applications, it's completely up to the individual application if it'll compress the data prior to it being shared or not.

However, if you're referring to the automatic upload to OneDrive, you can configure it from settings. See the following screenshots:

("Best quality" is uncompressed)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results by uploading to [OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3), then sharing from within that app.

From the Camera app --

1. view the video in question
2. tap the ... menu at the bottom
3. hit "Save to OneDrive"
4. Open OneDrive app
5. Navigate to "Mobile uploads"
6. tap and hold the video
7. select "send a link in email"

This works well and the video quality is excellent, but uploading can take some time.

Comment: Can't comment directly unfortunately, but following Nate's solution I get a "compressing video" note prior to the upload, this is by sharing or using auto sync, even though the settings are for 'best quality'. So frustrating! I guess email is the way, if your provider allows for large attachments